# The proper way to do exception handling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, exception

Now what I generally do when writing code is something like this

```
function changeBookAuthor(int $id, string $newName){
  if(!$newName){
   throw new MyAppException('No author name was provided');
  }

  $book = Books::find($id);

  if(!$book){
   throw new MyAppException('The provided book id could not be found');
  }
}
```

in the laravel doc we see:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        //
    }

    return parent::report($exception);
}
```

Now how to I properly handle the exception? they are all the same exception and they have no code neither. Should I provide an error code?

the problem with php exception is that they use integers. Is quite annoying imho. Better would be `'changeauthor_bookid_notfound'` as code instead of a random number. Should I create an exception class for each single exception? e.g. not reuse `MyAppException` that seems a bit tedious. I would have a trillion classes.

Now if for a special exception I want special handling, with my code, I cannot easily do it. I have no code to check for (e.g. `$exception->code == 3331 then do special`) and I don't have custom exception classes neither

what is a proven good solid way to handle this case?
code, new class on each error, something else all together?

and if provide a code, what is a nice way to do it?

Comment: It feels like you're overusing exceptions here. You're throwing an exception for every failed check. You don't necessarily need error codes in all your exceptions. You can use a single exception with different messages and then use the message when handling the exception. Also the you need to handle the exceptions in `render` method if you're planning on displaying custom errors/pages. The `report` method is only for the error reporting and logging.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way to do it would be to define either a custom Exception  class for each exception, or to define custom exceptions based on the type of error being thrown, however realize that Laravel already has many built in exceptions and mechanics for handling the use cases you outlined.

For instance, in the case of the "Book Not Found" exception, rather than manually triggering an exception yourself, you could use `Books::findOrFail($id);` which throws an instance of `ModelNotFoundException` when appropriate.

Also, in PHP there is no need to handle exceptions for unprovided arguments. Unless expressly denoted as optional, all method arguments are required, and Laravel will throw a PHP exception if an argument is missing.

Additionally, Laravel provides the `abort()` magic method which throws a HTTP error along with a custom error message and can be used like so:

```
abort(418, "I'm a teapot...")
```

So, if you must reinvent the wheel, the proper way is to define custom exception classes and define the custom handlers for those classes, but realize that Laravel already has many built in tools for managing exceptions without needing to do so.

Comment: findOrFail caused me soooo many problems because I didn't know exactly at what place the error was triggered. That is just some stuff coming from eloquent, far from optimal. Happens when you have no stack trace. Each time there is an error dig deep into some log file.. meh, kinda bad, no? Just something like "id not found" well good luck with that figuring out which of the 1000 findOrFail it was. 
if you look at the code, empty string would be a valid argument in the case of "laravel handles no arguments" so is kinda useless. There are a lot more non trivial examples for exceptions.

Comment: abort seems kinda the worst option to display an error, unless I am mistaken. Pretty much a die with http error code?
reinventing the wheel, sounds a bit odd. What you want in a professional application is top notch error handling. Because errors will happen, not even for bad coding, but 3rd party libs, systems that fail. For being a good programmer, this is not something optional.