# Intellij: create a random number via IDE to use as error number / error code?

Tags: intellij-idea

see here: [The proper way to do exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319497/the-proper-way-to-do-exception-handling)

say this code:

```
function changeBookAuthor(int $id, string $newName){
  if(!$newName){
   throw new MyAppException('No author name was provided');
  }

  $book = Books::find($id);

  if(!$book){
   throw new MyAppException('The provided book id could not be found');
  }
//..
}
```

i want to change that to:

```
 function changeBookAuthor(int $id, string $newName){
      if(!$newName){
       throw new MyAppException('No author name was provided', <SOMEVERYRANDOMNUMBER>);
      }

      $book = Books::find($id);

      if(!$book){
       throw new MyAppException('The provided book id could not be found', <SOMEVERYRANDOMNUMBER>);
      }
    //..
    }
```

can intellij help me in selecting random numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use different types of Exception instead of exception code.

For example:

```
try{
   ...
} catch (PDOException e1){
   // Show a message that we could not do SQL work
} catch (NumberFormatException e2){
   // Show a message that input was not a valid number
} catch (Exception e){
   // I'm not sure what was wrong but definitely there was some thing wrong
}
```

But if you still want random numbers, go to https://www.random.org, there are some number generators, copy values and define them as constants in your code (i guess that you are using PHP)

Comment: a bit tedious opening a website each time, no? I fear time to write my own plugin...